# Orientation inverted on display with bigger width than height

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have a device on which I set portrait orientation, but it shows the activity in landscape. The device width is bigger than its height, so it seems to be inverted. What can I do to have this device working like the others?

Note that this device has a keyboard; see [this image](http://opoliglota.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Samsung-Galaxy-Y-Pro-Duos-1.jpg).